# jQuery: How to call a jQuery plugin function on an element that hasn't yet been added to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.elements').fancyPlugin();
});
```

This works great until I start adding new elements:

```
$.get('ajax.html', function(data){
    $('#container').html(data);
});
```

I could call the plugin function again like this:

```
$.get('ajax.html', function(data){
    $('#container').html(data).find('.elements').fancyPlugin();
});
```

...except that the AJAX is happening inside another jQuery plugin that shouldn't have to know about the `fancyPlugin()`.

How can I apply this plugin to all current and future elements?

Comment: ok ok ok I know this one...... hrmmmm... ok maybe not completely but you should use an event listener. I would bind DOMNodeInserted on the document and call your function then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this will work in all browsers except IE:

```
document.body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event){
    var $elementJustAdded = $(event.target);
    if ($elementJustAdded.hasClass('elements')) {
        $elementJustAdded.fancyPlugin();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Why does this fail in IE?

Comment: This is now deprecated! See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Answer (score 12):

Another way of doing this is creating your own event :

```
var container=$('#container');
$.get('ajax.html', function(data){   
   container.html(data);
   $('.elements',container).trigger('added.yourns');    
});

container.on('added.yourns','.elements',function(){
  $(this).fancyPlugin();
});
```

Then, when adding ellements, simply trigger the event with the `trigger` method!

```
var aDiv=$('div');
aDiv.appendTo(someNode);
aDiv.trigger('added.yourns');
```

Doing so will enable you to attach any behaviour in any javascript file !

Comment: You answered a question for me that stuck in my head for months...and today I just needed this. You made someone happy, cheers :))))))))))))))))

Comment: This is great, helped solve something I was building.  Thanks!

Comment: What does this solve? If I have to eventually call `aDiv.trigger('added.yourns');`, why couldn't I just call `.fancyPlugin()` on the newly loaded node? We need to NOT have to call anything each time a new node is added; that's the whole point of this question, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you modify the same DOM element in many places, you are seeking for problems !

What it does solve is that you can listen on the event to call any plugins you need and not only one! You may have other handlers to read the new value or do other fancy stuff.

As you can see, it has its uses cases otherwise other people wouldn't have thanked me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If those elements are added with AJAX you could use the [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess) method:

```
$('#container').ajaxSuccess(function(result) {
    $('.elements').fancyPlugin();
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dvppN/3/).

Comment: Be careful: "As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxSuccess() method should only be attached to document." http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/

Answer (score 0):

Have your AJAX handler trigger some custom event like `contentAdded`, and bind `fancyPlugin` to that event.

Alternatively, you can use [DOM mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) to call `fancyPlugin` for any change in the container. Native browser support isn't quite there yet, but there are [plugins](https://www.adaptavist.com/display/jQuery/Mutation+Events) which should take care of that.

Comment: I wish you could show **how** to use the DOM mutation events!

Comment: Mutation events have been since then replaced by the [Mutation Observer](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers) which has [decent support](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutation). MDN has [a code example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  Essentially, you'd like something like:

```
$('selector').ready( ... do something ... );
```

The problem is that kind of logic isn't available.  Elements loading on the page don't trigger any specific events I'm aware of, they just inherit CSS from the DOM nodes above them.  What I would do is just, from the `$.get` success function, trigger a custom event.  The rest of your code can hook into that event to do any plugin reloading work that may be needed.  You can pass a list of relevant selectors with the event, and use that to invoke the appropriate plugins (you can keep a set of `selector -> plugin refresh function` relationships in a hashtable)

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the jQuery .live event handler? It automatically binds when a new item is added to the dom if it meets the specified requirements.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: As you can see, the `load` event is not implemented in jQuery's live function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196404/jquery-live-with-the-ready-or-load-event

Answer (score -1):

What if you make something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.elements').live('load', function () {
        $(this).fancyPlugin();
    })
});
```

The events are not re-binded after ajax calls or within the content they return. `live()` attaches a handler to the event now and in the future."

Comment: As you can see, the `load` event is not implemented in jQuery's live function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196404/jquery-live-with-the-ready-or-load-event