# Binding jquery function to future elements

Tags: jquery

How do I bind a function to future elements (elements that are added at run time)?
for example, see the code below:

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

I want to bind the placeholder function all the yet to be in the document "input" and "textarea"

P.S.
I know you can use jquery's "on" method to bind to the events but not very sure how i bind  functions (placeholder in this case) to future elements.

Comment: There are other similar questions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781661/jquery-how-to-call-a-jquery-plugin-function-on-an-element-that-hasnt-yet-been

Comment: Thanks @ClaudioRedi. that link has some work around to address this.

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind elements to events, for the future elements you need to use the delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input, textarea', placeholder);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more information on what event you can bind, and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only do this with events because of event propagation delegation. You will need to set up the placeholder on any new elements as they are inserted.